# Xquery delete with Xpath from sql:variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery-sql

I am having Xpath to delete from XML in an VARCHAR(MAX) variable, but `XML.modify('delete '+@MyXpath)` give an error ,

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "modify" must be a string
>   literal.

```
DECLARE @myXML XML,
        @MyXpath VARCHAR(MAX)

-- Processing of Xpaths for components needed to remove 
-- Adding those in @XpathsToRemove     

SELECT TOP(1) @MyXpath = [XPATH]
FROM @XpathsToRemove

SET @myXML.modify('delete '+@MyXpath)
```

Is there any way to remove those components with Xpath available in @MyXpath variable ?

-- Edit Example XML

```
DECLARE @myXML XML ='<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>'
      ,@MyXpath VARCHAR(MAX) = '//note/from'

      -- There are many Xpaths and dynamically generated with some processing so I don't want to hardcode Xpath there
      SET @myXML.modify('delete '+@MyXpath)

       --This doesn't works too
      -- SET @myXML.modify('delete "sql:variable("MyXPath")"')
      SELECT @myXML
```

Comment: *Is there any way?* Short answer: Yes, *dynamically created SQL* and `EXEC`. If you want help you must provide more details. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Shnugo If I create SQL and EXEC, then it is unable to interact with local variables i.e `@myXML`. I am not interested to do any changes on DB side, just to update that local `@XML` variable

Comment: How do you expect me to help? I do not know your variable, neither do I know the `XPath` you want to introduce. In general: What you try will not work! Please provide a working example: (reduced) XML and working statement with a literally written `.modify()`. Then explain which part you want to change dynamically and hope that someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: Btw: *it is unable to interact with local variables* Why do you think so?

Comment: `DECLARE @myXML XML ='<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>'
      ,@MyXpath VARCHAR(MAX) = '//note/from'

      SET @myXML.modify('delete '+@MyXpath)`

Comment: @Shnugo Edited question.
My XML are too long and Xpaths too in real cases. So I am unable to fit in Nchar too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128428/discussion-between-sayed-hussain-mehdi-and-shnugo).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I got solution by EXEC to generate dynamic queries.
Following is link that solved my issue,

[How to using for loop using XQuery to delete xml nodes [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264365/1887260)

Solution,

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(MAX)
SET @str = 'SET @MyXML.modify('+char(39)+'delete '+@MyXPath+'/*'+char(39)+'); '
EXEC sp_executesql  @str, N'@MyXML xml output', @MyXML output
```